# Google Play Games login fails

Tags: android, google-play-services

When I try to let the user sign in into Google+ via Google Game Services (using the GameHelper class), the login fails with this log-message:

```
05-16 17:34:44.620: ERROR/Volley(26441): [2299] il.a: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1whitelisted/applications?language=en_GB&platformType=ANDROID
05-16 17:34:44.620: ERROR/GameAgent(26441): Unable to retrieve 1P application xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com from network
05-16 17:34:44.625: INFO/GameAgent(26441): {"code":400,"errors":[{"message":"Invalid applicationId with value xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com","domain":"global","reason":"invalid"}]}
05-16 17:34:44.645: ERROR/CheckGameplayAcl(27604): Unable to load metadata for game
```

I've added all the metadata etc. correctly to my app and to the developer console, so it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app id should just be the number and not have "apps.googleusercontent.com" attached to it.

**Update:**
This seems to be related to not having a test account set up

See this question - [Google Play Game Services - unable to sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580885/google-play-game-services-unable-to-sign-in)

Comment: Just checking, your not still getting this are you "Invalid applicationId with value xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com" ?

Comment: I am still getting 

`05-16 18:18:02.375: ERROR/Volley(30222): [2603] il.a: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1whitelisted/applications?language=en_GB&platformType=ANDROID
05-16 18:18:02.375: ERROR/GameAgent(30222): Unable to retrieve 1P application xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx from network
05-16 18:18:02.400: ERROR/CheckGameplayAcl(31078): Unable to load metadata for game`

Comment: Does the developer console say your app is ready for testing?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of this problem is a mismatch between the client ID you registered in the Developer Console and your application's signing certificate. In order for sign-in to succeed, the **package name** and the **certificate fingerprint** you registered in your client ID should exactly match the package name and signing certificate of your application.

A common mistake is registering the release certificate's SHA1 fingerprint on developer console and then trying to sign the app with the debug certificate. Another common mistake is registering the wrong package name in the developer console.

Also, due to caching, sometimes editing an correcting an existing client ID might not solve the problem immediately. So, if you don't mind switching to a different package name, you might want to try creating a new project with a new package name.

A list of the most common setup issues can be found in our troubleshooting guide:

http://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

in my case: enable in firebase Google authentification method., it's work for me