# unable to retrieve application <id> from network

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

Trying to use google play services v- 0.9.34 on unity 5.3 but when I try to sign In google play pop up open and then stop.

Error in log cat :- 
"Unable to retrieve application xxxxxxxxxxxx from network.
Application ID xxxxxxxxxxxx is not associated with package com.company.game. Check the application ID in your manifest."

I already spent a lot time to get any solution, but I didn't found any solution. Any type of help really appreciate

Already checked these:
1. https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/216
2. [Google Play Game Services - unable to sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580885/google-play-game-services-unable-to-sign-in)
3. [Google Play Games login fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591808/google-play-games-login-fails)

```
public class FruitLevelSelect : MonoBehaviour {

private string leaderbord = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 


void Start()
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.Activate(); 

    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
        // handle success or failure
    });
}

public void Share()
{ 
    if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
    {
        ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).ShowLeaderboardUI(leaderbord);
    }
    else {
        Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
            if (success)
            {
                ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).ShowLeaderboardUI(leaderbord);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not Unity5, this is Unity3D. Know the tools you use.

Comment: sorry for that..and thanks for correcting it .any solution ??