# Do I need Google+ sign-in to use Google Play Game Services?

Tags: java, android, google-plus, google-play-games

I was trying to integrate a Google+ sign-in button into my app.  I kept getting this "Unknown error" that no one seems to have an answer too and its apparently an error that has been happening a lot since Google released this at their I/O recently.

[My SO thread on "Unknown error" here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032860/google-sign-in-results-in-a-unknown-error-google-play-game-services/17033047?noredirect=1#17033047)

So my question is if this Google+ sign-in button even necessary for me to integrate Google Play Game Services (GPGS) into my app?  If I use a feature of the GPGS, do I have to let the users log into Google+?  Ultimately all I want is to use the leaderboard feature of the GPGS and couldn't care less if they are logged into Google+.

Answer (score 2):

No buttons are truly *necessary*, but they are the best way to communicate to the user that they can sign in with Google. If you just want to use leaderboards, here's how to do it:

1. Perform setup and create your game's client ID as [described in our docs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling).
2. [Configure the leaderboard](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/configuring) in the developer console.
3. Set up [one or more test accounts](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub) to use to test your app.

Once that's done you're ready to start your code. Download the [samples](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/) to serve as a starting point.

1. Import BaseGameUtils to your workspace.
2. Import the Google Play Services library project into your workspace (you can find it in the SDK manager under Extras, Google, Google Play Services)
3. Derive your Activity class from the sample's BaseGameActivity
4. Add a sign-in button in your layout (see sample's layout XML)
5. When the user clicks the button, call `beginUserInitiatedSignIn()`.
6. When you get `onSignInSucceeded`, hide the sign-in button. Now you're ready to make any API calls, including submit leaderboard scores!

Hope this helps.

If not, please take a look at our [Troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting) too, to see if there are any setup issues you might be overlooking.

Comment: So, does that mean that the users do need to be signed into Google+ in order to be able to use leaderboard/achievements? Or would it be possible to set/pass the username when submitting scores? e.g. if you have "Login with Facebook" already implemented and the majority of your users don't have Google+ account