# Libgdx game exits when Google play signin called

Tags: libgdx, admob, google-play-services

Hi I made game in LibGx and integrated Google play services for achievments and leaderboard
I published the game all was good

Then I decided to integrate [Admob](https://github.com/TheInvader360/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads/blob/master/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads-android/src/com/theinvader360/tutorial/libgdx/google/ads/MainActivity.java)

Now when I tried to sign In my app exits with this error also waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing google play game services

somethis like this in logs

```
09-01 18:50:07.014: E/Volley(1005): [142] tm.a: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/114331978856382749964?language=en_IN
    09-01 18:50:07.065: W/GLSUser(672): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
    09-01 18:50:07.088: D/IPCThreadState(1005): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x5c1e8808
    09-01 18:50:07.098: I/SurfaceFlinger(124): [SurfaceFlinger] fps:66.609230,dur:1005.87,max:54.44,min:2.09
    09-01 18:50:07.140: E/SignInIntentService(1005): Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.
    09-01 18:50:07.140: E/SignInIntentService(1005): exe
    09-01 18:50:07.140: E/SignInIntentService(1005):    at eqe.a(SourceFile:146)
    09-01 18:50:07.140: E/SignInIntentService(1005):    at dvt.a(SourceFile:580)
    09-01 18:50:07.140: E/SignInIntentService(1005):    at dvt.a(SourceFile:561)
    09-01 18:50:07.140: E/SignInIntentService(1005):    at dug.a(SourceFile:850)
    09-01 18:50:07.140: E/SignInIntentService(1005):    at eyi.a(SourceFile:251)
    09-01 18:50:07.140: E/SignInIntentService(1005):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesSignInIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:390)
    09-01 18:50:07.140: E/SignInIntentService(1005):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
    09-01 18:50:07.140: E/SignInIntentService(1005):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    09-01 18:50:07.140: E/SignInIntentService(1005):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    09-01 18:50:07.140: E/SignInIntentService(1005):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

does any here knw how to integrate admob and google play services in libgdx game together.

Comment: Judging by the stacktrace you have proguard obfuscation enabled. Check the projects proguard/mapping.txt to be able to debug the stacktrace.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688029/unexpected-response-code-403-for-https-www-googleapis-com-games-v1-players-112 most likely something was wrong with API Settings

Answer (score 1):

After having a rough day going through lots of website i didnt find the way to resolve this

But I got it worked by other way around by changing the sequence of method call that I was doing for GPGS and admob

Now I set ip admob first and then added a button to sign in In GPGS earlier I was doing that in onCreate....

so Cheers ....