# Google Play Game Services - unable to sign in

Tags: android, google-play, leaderboard

Recently I try to implement a leaderboard by Google Play Game Service.
And first I import that sample project TypeANumber. I follow the way here https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart step by step.

I used the keytool to generated the SHA1 of keystore, and use this SHA1 to verify the app.
Then I sign the app by the keystore.

When I run the sample and try to sign in. I got the error "Google Play Game Services - unable to sign in".

Then I double check all my steps and try again. Still got this error.

I searched this problem on google, and I find this man got the same problem with me
[Google Play Game Services - unable to sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580885/google-play-game-services-unable-to-sign-in)

All the situation is the same.  And he got the solution.

I follow his solution delete my app client ID on Google APIs Console, unlinked my app and relinked it with the proper Certificate Fingerprint.

All this work done, I still got the same error.

Did I miss something?  Any body got the same problem like this ?
Or maybe I should create an app with the same package name of the sample project and upload the apk ?
Or maybe Google Play Game Service doesn't work at China ?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar issues and I note that this page was updated on 30th May 2013 which
may help you, or me, or maybe even both of us !

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting

Update: I worked my way through this and eventually realised that I had two different app_id strings in my project - one for the Facebook API and one for Google play Game Services! The two strings were stored in different files so my error was hard to find. Once I renamed one everything worked fine. One problem that I have encountered is that I am unable to test with the id that I used to define the Game in the developer console. Other people have mentioned this elsewhere on SO but no harm mentioning it again.