# Google Developer Console - Enabling accounts for testing doesn't work

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I'am currently trying to get a sample application (from [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart)) working. Therefore you have to add accounts that can access the service as long as the application is not published. BUT when I#m trying to add a email the console is keep saying me that my email address cannot be used because it is no google+ account and/or not a googlemail address - but it is! It's my gmail address and I can log in to my google plus account with it, so what is it I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that there are problems with 'old' @googlemail accounts. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580885/google-play-game-services-unable-to-sign-in) (the comment from ottl142 that those "indeed" not work).

So **I made my self a new @gmail account, add it as testaccount, and see its working.** 
Guess Google has still some problems with its new service.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the same account you publish apps with?
That account is always enabled, plus if you use that you don't need to upload your apk first to test it :)

Comment: No I tried to add the one of my girlfriend too (same: google+ and gmail) and that's not working too :( plus when i try the sample app the login per google button gives me an unknown error (but i guess thats because of the testaccounts not enabled)

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. We tried 10 different beta tester and it won't work. We tried 20 times and one worked after this crazy adding session...

Solution found:
The beta tester shoudl login to their googlemail account. Click on the right Button and a dropdown opens up. Choose settings and go to the tab Account? (in German "Konto"). There a user can switch the old googlemail to gmail. After doing this step everyone can be added as a tester.