# Google Play Services and "There is no linked app associated with this client ID"

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to implement Google Play Services following Google's documentation and I'm seeing the following when I try to connect my `GameClient`:

```
E/Volley: [4953] il.a: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me
E/Volley: [4953] il.a: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me
E/SignInIntentService: There is no linked app associated with this client ID.
```

I've checked that the SHA1 fingerprint of the certificate signing the APK, the SHA1 of the debug certificate, and the SHA1 given to the Google API do match up and they do. I've checked that the app id is declared in the manifest in the application item (I've taken in my case the 13 digit numerical id, not one that also includes a package). I've also checked that the test accounts I'm using are each listed in the Developer Console and they are; they're each @gmail.com too, and they include my developer address. They've each activated Google Plus.

I've tried this from an API 16 S3 device and an API 17 Google API simulator. The app's package name is correctly declared in the manifest, on the developer console and matches the API package name. The app is listed as a client of the game service, and is shown as 'ready for testing'.

In short I'm struggling to see what my mistake can be and what I've missed. I think I have everything from Google's troubleshooting addressed too. I've looked at the main questions here on StackOverflow, and they're covered. Whatever it is I'm missing is probably staring me full in the face. What can I be missing?

Answer (score 4):

I got stuck on this problem for a long time until I realised that I had two strings in my app called "app_id". One from the Facebook SDK and one from Google. I renamed the Google app_id (and changed the corresponding manifest reference) and all was well.

It is POSSIBLE that you have a similar problem. If you can't see the error then I would try to write out the app_id to syslog to confirm that this is not the cause of the problem.

Incidentally, all my Google app_id s (client ids) are 12 bytes not 13, so perhaps you should start by checking that.

Good Luck !

Comment: Thanks Ian. I can't accept your answer here as this is not my problem, but I'm happy to up vote because it is pertinent - as it happens I am migrating an existing project away from using Facebook in favour of Google Plus, but I had already removed the reference to the Facebook app id. Your suggestion is likely to help many people who land here. I'm about to post what my problem seems to have been, but I'm not going to accept my answer either in the hope that this question becomes a catch all.

Comment: In my case, I recreated my debug key and my problem went away seemingly on its own. I'm scratching my head a bit.

Comment: Thats fine - just trying to help !

Answer (score 2):

Even after redoing everything, *everything*, I still encountered the same problem. However, I subsequently encountered a "This package is already in use" error message on Google API even though I had undeleted all projects and removed all clients before deleting these again.

This turned out to be a blessing: The solution to this was to recreate my debug key before adding the new fingerprint to Google API in another new client id.

And lo... my original problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

I hade the same problem and for me it worked to re-link the app in `Game services -> Linked apps -> Link another app`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't explicitly state that the gmail accounts you're testing with are added as Google Plus users in a Google Plus community that is configured as the testing community for your app -OR- that you're using a google group as the testing community and those gmail accounts are part of that community.

If you have done those things, then it might be the issue stated here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=554

This answer might sound encouraging to solve your problem, but don't get your hopes up. I've done all that the original poster did, plus the things above, and I'm still stuck.

I've even followed all of the tips stated here:

[Google Play Game Services - unable to sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580885/google-play-game-services-unable-to-sign-in?rq=1)

And it would appear the depths of the chasm that Google lets you fall into regarding GPS is far deeper than the depths I've plumbed. Joy.

Comment: OK, I've finally fixed my particular problem. The key was in another SO posting, which I'll summarize here. Your Oauth2 client CAN NOT be created from Google APIs Console, it MUST be created from the Google Play UI.

1. Delete your OAuth2 Client in Google APIs Console if you created it manually.
2. Re-add your Game Services client under Linked Apps in the Google Play UI. If you've already published, just add another one. You can verify it created your Oauth2 client in Google APIs Console, and then your testers/apps should work if that's all that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ,I am not sure that the following action is the one that resolved the problem but its worth the try,

Seems that I didnt had the Drive API enabled ,I had it in the enabled apis but i had to actually  click the gear icon next to it and then click enable and provide the application name.

Answer (score 0):

Just link the same package as many times as you have Client ID's in your Developer Console "Debug & Release Client ID's"

The thing is if you link your app to the Game Services with the wrong SHA1 fingerprint, Games Services will pick it up and associate it as the main Client ID.

Once you link the same app again to your Game Services, it will automatically pick up the other Client ID's

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, and in my case, I fixed it regenerating the API Key from the Google APIs Console. Go to Credentials, select your API key and then click on "Regenerate Key". You don't need to update anything in your code or link more apps, just regenerate and it starts working magically.

[image]