# Android studio - Google Play Game Services sign in fails

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-play-games

I know, this question already exists in many shapes but I can't still solve my problem.
The issue is that when I run my application and try to sign in with Google Play Game Services it shows me this message:

**"The application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developer Console. Also, if the application is not yet published, check that the account you are trying to login with is listed as a tester account. See logs for more information."**

What I've already tried:

- ensure the package name on my AndroidManifest.xml was correct
- checked my SHA1 and compared with the SHA1 of my linked app (even created a new one with the same SHA1 just to be sure)
- added my Google+ account to the tester list
- wrote the code:

  android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
          android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"

with the correct ID in my string value

But the error is still not fixed. Now I've just thought the issue cold be on the segment of code:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

but I'm not able to find this value to check it (I'm working on a libgdx project and the google_play_service package is not in my project hierarchy but everything else works fine). Not sure if this could be my problem, what else could I do?

Comment: You're not using the SHA1 of your debug keystore, right? Did you sign the APK with the correct key?

Comment: Don't debug . Choose release .

Comment: I have only one key, I've never created a debug one

Answer (score 1):

Definitely start with the debug certificate if you are testing your app.

To summarize: this often happens when you should use the Debug SHA, but instead you are using the Release info for your Linked App (the section you filled out in the Google Play Developer Console when authorizing your app).

You may know a lot of this already, but:

Go to your Gradle View, by clicking on the vertical Gradle tab in the far right of Android Studio.

[image]

Or you can open it with Menus: View > Tool Windows > Gradle

When the Gradle View is open, it will look like this:

[image]

Double-click on the section called signingReport (in :app / Tasks / android) as highlighted in blue above.

That will run a signingReport usually in the Run pane of Android Studio (which is at the bottom of the interface, usually where you work with the Android Monitor by default). You can get your debug SHA1, by copying the line on your own signingReport whose location I indicated in red in the image below (an example of SHA1 excluding my ellipsis at the end looks like this):

cf:23:df:22:07:d9:9a:74:fb...

[image]

Then you will paste that into the Linked App section of the Google Play Developer Console when it asks for the SHA1.

Did you already create a Debug APK? That is something else you may have to look at if you have not:

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#studio

You can create a Debug APK exactly like a Release APK, but at the last step of the link above, choose debug, instead of release.

Also take a look at this for general thoughts on where else you may gotten off-track: [Google Play Game Services : Debug AND Release certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408967/google-play-game-services-debug-and-release-certificate?lq=1)

One place in particular is if you used Google Developer Console instead of Google **Play** Developer Console.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error (after exporting the `ids.xml` from google games serivces console), I fixed it by:

1. Enabling verbose logging for games:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.Games VERBOSE
```

Then I made the error happened and got this error:

```
2019-07-25 20:30:20.189 2241-28188/? E/SignInAuthenticator: ****
    **** APP NOT CORRECTLY CONFIGURED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY GAME SERVICES
    **** This is usually caused by one of these reasons:
    **** (1) Your package name and certificate fingerprint do not match
    ****     the client ID you registered in Developer Console.
    **** (2) Your App ID was incorrectly entered.
    **** (3) Your game settings have not been published and you are 
    ****     trying to log in with an account that is not listed as
    ****     a test account.
    ****
    **** To help you debug, here is the information about this app
    **** Package name         : com.my.package.name
    **** Cert SHA1 fingerprint: AB:CD:EF:12:34:56:78:90:....
    **** App ID from manifest : 1234567890123
    ****
    **** Check that the above information matches your setup in 
    **** Developer Console. Also, check that you're logging in with the
    **** right account (it should be listed in the Testers section if
    **** your project is not yet published).
    ****
    **** For more information, refer to the troubleshooting guide:
    ****   http://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting
    ****
```

Copy the hash from the error message and go to the google play services console.

1. Click games services
2. Click your game
3. Click linked apps
4. Link another app
5. Click Android
6. Fill out the details
7. Click save and continue
8. In the box that pops up, paste in the SHA1 hash from above
9. Click save and then publish changes