# There is no linked app associated with this client ID

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm becoming crazy with this one. I just published a game on Google Play Store and the game uses the Google Play Games services.

Sign-in and leaderboards / achievements worked fined with the application signed with the debug key, but since I built and
published my app using my release key, Google+ sign-on is impossible. I always get the infamous error 
**"E/SignInIntentService(25004): There is no linked app associated with this client ID."**

I double- and triple-checked everything : my app is published, the package name and SHA1 fingerprint are correct and match
what I extracted from the release APK, I unlinked and relinked the app in the Google Play Console multiple times, but nothing
works.

Ideas, anyone ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I did all that and everything was fine. However, I read and re-read some others posts here about the problem and found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16970716/764645). [user2267794](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2267794/user2267794) nailed it for me.
Since I had just released my game, I had removed by debug OAuth Client Id, thinking it was no longer needed – for some time at least.

On the brink of giving up, out of desperation and having nothing to lose, I tried what [user2267794](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2267794/user2267794) had done and linked my app a second time with my debug key SHA1. And it magically worked immediately. Using the release key without the debug one doesn't seem to work for me, for whatever reason.
If it's not a bug, I don't know what is.

Comment: How did you do that? When I link my app a second time I don't see any possibility to enter a SHA1 key.

Comment: IIRC, I used the old console, in the 'API Access' section ([link](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/))

Comment: So you didn't link the app two times but just created another Client ID for your app such that you have two "Client IDs for installed applications" there? That's the same I did but unfortunately without success. I've got my two "Client IDs for installed applications": one with the debug SHA1 fingerprint and the other with the true SHA1 fingerprint but when my app tries to sign in it doesn't work. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507927/app-not-correctly-configured-to-use-google-play-game-services).

Comment: Actually, my app is linked *four times* (yep, with the same package name and ID). That's because I tried about anything, just like you and many others did, until it worked for some mysterious reason.
And I can't remove the extra links, but I am too afraid to break something.

It's not helpful for you, I know, but I can tell you this : I am convinced this Google functionality is broken but Google won't do squat, unless you're Rovio or King. We all did what was explained and failed, until it worked. Remove everything and try again.

Comment: The problem is that I've already published the app. This means I can't remove the linked app. I only can add the same app again and again (up to 20 times). But at [this page](https://console.developers.google.com/project/568558800664/apiui/credential) I can't tell Google for which linked app my Client ID is supposed to be. This is because the app appears [here](https://console.developers.google.com/project) still as one project. By the way, which APIs should be turn on [here](https://console.developers.google.com/project/568558800664/apiui/api)? I've never changed there anything manually.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. All you need to do is to make sure before creating a new game, you input the exact package name and the fingerprint certificate (SHA1) that matches your release keystore. My problem is that I put a default fingerprint in the game and decided to change it later. Somehow the google console developer can still detect your previous fingerprint even though you replace it with your final fingerprint. The solution was to delete the first game configuration and created a new one. No need to create or attach your debug certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Is Game Services published in the Google Developer Console? That's a separate step.

If your app itself isn't published (i.e. in beta), only those google accounts associated with a specified google+ or google groups account designated to be your pool of testers will be able to connect.

You also need to verify that the app_id compiled into your app (often in /res/strings.xml) matches the google api console ID. For example there should be a line like:

```
<string name="app_id">123456789123</string>
```

And don't get it confused with your facebook application_id!

Beyond that you'll need to check the Google Cloud Console under Overview -> APIs & auth -> Registered apps and verify that the prefix for CLIENT ID matches, that the PACKAGE NAME is correct, and the CERTIFICATE FINGERPRINT (SHA1) matches.

If it doesn't work after all that, you'll be roughly where I find myself currently-- having done all that and still stuck.

Comment: OK, I've finally fixed my particular problem. The key was in another SO posting, which I'll summarize here. Your Oauth2 client CAN NOT be created from Google APIs Console, it MUST be created from the Google Play UI. 1. Delete your OAuth2 Client in Google APIs Console if you created it manually. 2. Re-add your Game Services client under Linked Apps in the Google Play UI. If you've already published, just add another one. You can verify it created your Oauth2 client in Google APIs Console, and then your testers/apps should work if that's all that's wrong.

Comment: same problem here. But now linked app does not give me option to add SHA1 key. This is crazy

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Google Play Service...

Don't try to login to the Game Service unless you upload first APK and link the game in Game Service (putting a proper package name is not enought, there must be an first APK uploaded, so during the linking process you can select the app from suggestion list)...

When you try to login before linking first, the services comes into "bad state" and even after you assign a game to the service, the Auth process still claims that it is not linked....

I have made 6 games and had this issue 2 times. The solution is to delete corrupted Game Service. Create new one (recreate whole CFG - sorry about that), reassign APP ID in a game, link the game to the Game Service (through the suggestion list) and then try to login in into service...

Be careful because there is also a lot of misunderstanding "false" notification in the logcat....

Comment: could you please be more specific about the process? What do you mean by "recreate whole CFG"? How do you delete corrupted Game Service?

Answer (score 0):

I tried linking a new app and it didn't work and almost started the process of creating a new app again. However, I tried regenerating the API Key from the [Google APIs Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) and it worked!

Go to Credentials, select your API key and then click on "Regenerate Key".

[image: regenerate-api-key]

Answer (score 0):

Just To Help Others-

Please keep this in mind while implementing Google Play Services:

> Warning: Do not create new client IDs for your game from the Google
>   API Console. If you do so, Google Play games services will not
>   associate your game settings with the client ID, and this could cause
>   errors during gameplay.