# Cert SHA1 fingerprint generated at debug does not match with the keystore I'm using

Tags: android, ssl, google-play-services

This is the issue: When I run my app which is using Google Play Game Services I got an error trying to sign in "The application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name and sign in certificate match the client ID created in Developer Console".

I checked the suggested and everything look OK, but reading the Logcat I noted the SHA1 fingerprint is not the same of my .keystore file. It's a little confused because when I execute the keytool command to view the .keystore file information, I can see the same SHA1 that is related with my app id in the Developer Console.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. When you configure Google Play Game Services, you have to add the SHA1 fingerprint of you .keystore file and **ALSO** you have to add the debug.keystore file located at .../.android/, both fingerprints are added at the linked application link in the Developer Console. It is because when I run my app the .keystore file used was not configured at Developer Console, where the default SHA1 taken is the release.