# Unity Game not correctly configured to use google play game services

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am unable to connect to Google Play services on my Unity build. I want to test my app build and applied all the possible solutions.

I have this issue when I debug my app.

```
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): ****
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): ****
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): **** APP NOT CORRECTLY CONFIGURED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY GAME SERVICES
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): **** This is usually caused by one of these reasons:
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): **** (1) Your package name and certificate fingerprint do not match
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): ****     the client ID you registered in Developer Console.
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): **** (2) Your App ID was incorrectly entered.
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): **** (3) Your game settings have not been published and you are 
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): ****     trying to log in with an account that is not listed as
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): ****     a test account.
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): ****
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): **** To help you debug, here is the information about this app
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): **** Package name         : *****
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): **** Cert SHA1 fingerprint: *****
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): **** App ID from          : *****
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): ****
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): **** Check that the above information matches your setup in 
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): **** Developer Console. Also, check that you're logging in with the
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): **** right account (it should be listed in the Testers section if
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): **** your project is not yet published).
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): ****
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): **** For more information, refer to the troubleshooting guide:
03-19 14:22:36.126: W/GameHelper(15312): ****   http://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting
```

The solution I found for this problem is

[[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507927/app-not-correctly-configured-to-use-google-play-game-services]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65020202/unity-game-not-correctly-configured-to-use-google-play-game-services)

But this solution doesn't work with the new Google Play Console. I am unable to add SHA-1 on the new Google Play Console. Anyone, please help me sort out how can we add SHA-1 on new Google Play console 2020.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks..!

Answer (score 1):

if you want back up you phone and reset youre phone and restore that back up this should work as it worked for me many times

have a good day khurrira

Comment: thanks for your answer. but please read my question carefully. I am facing issue with new Google Play console.