# Project showing up in Google Play Dev Console, but not in Google Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play

I have a google play app, linked to a google play game services project. However, I believe I accidentally deleted the google play game services project from the google developer console, so now it shows up in google play developer console, but not in the google developer console. In the google play developer console, in the game services project, I'm constantly getting 
`An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (1700404)`
 (I'm assuming this is because the underlying developer console project was deleted). Well, now it's really screwed up because I can't  add a new game services project, but the current one isn't going to work. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the error you are getting ? I assume you are not trying to use the same apk name ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you start again from the beginning with a new app in the Google Play Developer Console (i.e. use a different apk name). Do not make changes to Google Play Game Services apps in the developer console (if indeed that is its current name) unless specifically instructed to do so by a reliable source (e.g. a google guide).

You will find many tales of woe on Stack Overflow concerning problems arising from making changes in the developer console to Google Play Game Services apps. e.g :

[Google Play Game Services - unable to sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580885/google-play-game-services-unable-to-sign-in/16888332#16888332)