# Google developer console - Project ID or Project number

Tags: android, xml, google-app-engine, google-play-services, google-developer-tools

I've been using this tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin?authuser=1#implementing_player_sign-in) to implement the Google sign-in button to my app.

I have my project name and ID from the Google Developer Console [proof of project id and number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztjXM.png)

I've put the number in the `strings.xml` file and added

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
           android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

My app runs fine but when I try to sign-in using the Google sign-in button I added to my activity, I get the following error in my LogCat.

```
03-08 17:45:59.626 2073-12290/? E/GameAgent: Unable to retrieve application 522187312304 from network
03-08 17:45:59.626 2073-12290/? E/GameAgent: Application 522187312304 is not associated with package com.example.healyj36.quizapp. Check the application ID in your manifest.
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, am I using the wrong ID / number?

Also, I'm confused by the `Google Developer Console` and `Google Play Developer Console`. Whats the difference between them? Am I using the wrong one? (I'm using Google Developer Console)

Answer (score 1):

As I have read, [**Google Developers Console**](https://console.developers.google.com) is where you create a client ID, which you need to call the sign-in API. You must have a Google Developers Console project before you can integrate Google Sign-In into your app.

Otherwise, [**Google Play Developer Console**](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) is where you upload apps, build your product pages, configure prices and distribution, and publish. You can manage all phases of publishing on Google Play through the Developer Console, from any web browser.

For the error **E/GameAgent: Unable to retrieve application 522187312304 from network**, try to delete your app client ID on Google APIs Console, unlinked your app, then relinked it with the proper SHA1 fingerprint.

Check this [SO ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580885/google-play-game-services-unable-to-sign-in) which is related to your problem.