# Using Google Play Services on different computers (VCS)

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm programming an android app an added Google Play Services for Google Sign-In support. Therefore I generated and downloaded my configuration file from Google's developer console. I integrated the file into the app folder and everything works fine while sign in with google in my app so far.

Now I wanted to share my Project with another colaborator, but when she pulled the code from GitHub, she cannot sign in successfully. When she tries to sign-in the GoogleSignInResult-object has the following status: Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}. As I looked up in the internet it is probably an issue with the configuration file and the correspondig SHA1-key, but I didn't find a solution.

Does anybody know how to solve thies issue?

Comment: First do you need if she has the same configuration as you in her Android Studio (specially on the SDK Tools, Build Tools, Platform Tools), you need check the two environments are equals. 
Other stuff is her device, maybe has a last version of Google Play Services, I had a issue using Fused Location I couldn't run properly on one phone, was because that phone never was installed Google Maps actualizations.

Answer (score 0):

[DEVELOPER_ERROR](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/api/com/google/android/gms/appstate/AppStateStatusCodes.html#constants)

> The developer has configured something incorrectly with their
>   application. This is a hard error, since retrying will not fix this.

Maybe the issue is Google Play services was unable to find a matching client from the console based on the SHA1 and package name.

You can follow this [guidelines](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#check_the_certificate_fingerprint) on how to troubleshoot the problem about SHA1.

The certificate with which you are signing your game should match the certificate fingerprint associated to your client ID. To verify this, first check your certificate's SHA1 fingerprint:

Find your certificate file and obtain its SHA1 fingerprint. To obtain the SHA1 fingerprint, run this command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias your-key-name -keystore /path/to/your/keystore/file -list -v
```

Take note of the sequence of hexadecimal digits labeled SHA1: in the output. That is your certificate's fingerprint.

> Note: If you are using a debug certificate, replace your-key-name with
>   androiddebugkey in the command above. If using a release certificate,
>   use the name you chose for your key when creating the certificate.

For more information and the next step, just check the link in the guidelines above.

Also check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580885/google-play-game-services-unable-to-sign-in?rq=1), it might help you also to solve your problem.